# Result not displayed if i enter the carno on textbox Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am creating a car retail system. i need to the display if i enter the correct carid relavent car information will be diplayed the below textboxs. i attached the screen shot image below. i need to calcaluating day differnt start date and end date for calculation retail fee of the retail system in c# i wrote like this 
**select car_id,cust_id,due,DATEDIFF(GETDATE(),due) as elap from rental where car_id = ?**

in Asp.net MVC i don't how to write. what i tried i attached below.

Screenshot image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTlVK.jpg)

code i tied

**form design**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "return", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "popupForm" }))
        {
            <div>
                <h4> Registation</h4>
            </div>

              <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Car ID</label>
                  <input type="text" id="carno" name="carno" class="form-control" placeholder="carno" required />
            </div>



            <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Customer ID</label>

                <input type="text" id="custid" name="custid" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer ID" required />

            </div>



            <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Date</label>

                <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required />

            </div>


             <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Days Elapsed</label>

                 <input type="text" id="elap" name="elap" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required />

            </div>


             <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Fine</label>

                 <input type="text" id="fine" name="fine" class="form-control" placeholder="Fine" required />

            </div>


            <div class="card">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>

        }
    </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery** seach the data using jquery

```
   <script>
        getProductcode();
        function getProductcode() {
            $("#carno").empty();
            $("#carno").keyup(function (e)
            {
                var q = $("#carno").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/return/Getid?carno=' + $("#carno").val(),
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                          $('#custid').val(data.custid);



                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error)
                    {
                        //  alert("The barcode entered is not correct");
                    }
                });
                return true;
            });
        }

    </script>
```

**returnController**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Getid(String carno)
        {
            carrentEntities1 db = new carrentEntities1();
            var carn = (from s in db.rentails where s.carno == carno select s.custid).ToList();
            return Json(carn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

i don't know how to write the Dateiff to calculating days. in this no result displayed i tested custid it didn't diplay.

Databse fields

```
id  carno   custid  fee   sdate      edate
1   1        1     1200  2019-12-09  2019-12-19
2   1        1     20000 2019-12-01  2019-12-31
3   A0001    1     3434  2019-12-09  2019-12-27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You should study how to use DATEDIFF method in sql via  [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)

Secondly, In server side (Asp.net MVC), You just return .FirstOrDefault instead of .Tolist.
Simply becuz, As i can see, in client side you just get one item **($('#custid').val(data[0].custid);**)

Finally, In my opinion, keyup event should combine with [Debounce pattern](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) to avoid calling server too much time unnecessarily.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203900/discussion-on-answer-by-phong-nguyen-result-not-displayed-if-i-enter-the-carno-o).